# Extract consecutive negative values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have this df

```
         col
252      73.9

253     -71.8

254     -314.6

255     -202

256     -19.4

257      46.9

258      139.4
```

and I want to extract the consecutive  `-ve` values from `253 to 256`. I have tried `(df.col < 0) & (df.col.shift(1) < 0)` and it gets `254 to 256` but misses out `253`. How should I change it to get the required values?

Comment: Can you add some values which are negative and non consecutive? Because then not clear if separate negative values has to be removed, or not. thanks.

Answer (score 4):

If you are only interested in the index:

```
df.loc[df.lt(0).col].index.tolist()

[253, 254, 255, 256]
```

If you need the dataframe of consecutive values:

```
df.loc[df.lt(0).col]

      col
253 -71.8
254 -314.6
255 -202.0
256 -19.4
```

Comment: `df.index[df.lt(0).col]`? @jezrael

Comment: nice, removes the need to bother with the dataframe, just the index. cool.

Comment: That would be even faster.

Comment: not a problem, i'll take it out

Comment: I have tried df.loc[df.lt(0).col] and it is giving me the error 'TypeError: Could not operate 0 with block values '<' not supported between instances of 'numpy.ndarray' and 'int'. why is it doing so?

Comment: hmmm. what's the outcome if u run ```df.lt(0)``` ? Alternatively, as others have suggested, it is much better and faster if u use ```df.col.lt(0)```

Comment: when I run df.It(0) it says 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'It' and in df.col.lt(0) case, it says Series has no attribute It.

Comment: [lt](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lt.html) is a pandas's method. i'm wondering if it has anything to do with ur pandas version?

Answer (score 4):

Solution for filter only negative values, not consecutive negative values:

For improve performance filter `index` values by mask by one column `col` in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df.index[df.col.lt(0)].tolist()
```

For filter all columns `loc` is not important, it is used for filter column and by mask:

```
df[df.col.lt(0)]

#for filter only one column to Series
df.loc[df.col.lt(0), 'col']

#for filter only one column to DataFrame
df.loc[df.col.lt(0), ['col']]
```

---

For filtering consecutive negatives use:

```
print (df)
       col
252   73.9
253  -71.8
254 -314.6
255 -202.0
256  -19.4
257   46.9
258 -202.0 <- removed, because not consecutive.
259  139.4


m = df.col.lt(0)

df = df[(~m).cumsum()[m].duplicated(keep=False).reindex(df.index, fill_value=False)]
print (df)
       col
253  -71.8
254 -314.6
255 -202.0
256  -19.4
```

Another solution:

```
m = df.col.lt(0)

df = df[ m.ne(m.shift()).cumsum().duplicated(keep=False) & m]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `.loc` accessor to select `253` through to `256` (`df.loc[253:256,:]`)
Boolean select and mask values values less than zero

```
df=(df[df.loc[253:256,:]<0]).dropna() 

    col1
253 -71.8
254 -314.6
255 -202.0
256 -19.4
```

To list please

```
df[df.loc[253:256,:]<0].index.tolist()

 [253, 254, 255, 256]
```